# ngc: Error: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module but cannot be named

Tags: angular

### Code

```
this.store.select(state => state.user).subscribe(u => user = u).unsubscribe();
```

https://gist.github.com/nottinhill/eac309590096cc6f1b910f40a1b2f0c3
https://gist.github.com/nottinhill/5dc4026007a0c3ea3a4e0c15c0adfe05

### Error

```
[02:25:41]  ngc: Error: Error at /Users/tyrion/devel/saveup-front/.tmp/+purchase/shared/purchase-service/purchase.service.ts:22:12: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module "/Users/tyrion/devel/saveup-front/node_modules/rxjs/Observable" but cannot be named.
```

### Problem

Where to strong-type to type Observable here? I can't get it to compile with what I tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is something strange but I managed to fix it with private method inside service: 
where you place `this.store.select(state => state.user)` method, if you are using `import {Http} from "@angular/http";` make sure you doing something near this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  getList() {
    var url = 'http://<URL_HERE>';
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);

    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

I added this method `extractData` to make it work, if you can provide your service will be better to figure out the issue.

Comment: hummm, weird solution you found. Did you try changing the import to `import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";` instead? from what I understood about that error, it happens when you import an alias of it instead of the original path. That approach has solved all my issues which were related

Answer (score 1):

I had to put `Observable:<any>` into the public functions that return any Observables, also if these were returned from an imported class or service.